# I am trying to store and read an Array of number that are input by a user

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am hoping it looks like this:

```
Lottery analysis

How many days will you analyze? 5

Day 1: 123
Day 2: 1234
too many digits
Day 2: abc
non-numeric data

Day 2: 456
Day 3: 789
Day 4: 012
Day 5: 345

Frequencies

0: 1
1: 2
2: 2
3: 2
4: 2
5: 2
6: 1
7: 1
8: 1
9: 1
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Lottery Analysis\n");

    // Create Scanner
    Scanner days = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Ask the user for how many days they will analyze
    System.out.print("How many days will you analyze? ");
    int analyze = days.nextInt();

    // Ask the user to enter 3 digits for each day
    System.out.println("\nEnter 3 digits for each day \n");
    Scanner scanDigits = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 1;

    // Make a loop that prints the number of days so the user can input the digits each time into that day
    String digits3;
    do {
        System.out.print("Day " + i + ": ");
        digits3 = scanDigits.nextLine();

        // Make sure the string used holds only 3 digits
        if (isNumeric(digits3)) {
            i++;
            // Store all digits used in digits3 in an array
            int[] frequencies = new int[10];
            int val = Character.digit(digits3.charAt(0),10);
        }
    }
    while (i <= analyze);

    // Print the Numbers and Frequencies from 0 to 9
    System.out.println("\nFrequencies\n");
    System.out.println(val);
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String digits3)
{
    boolean ret = !digits3.equals("");
    for(int i = 2; i < digits3.length(); i++)
    {
        // Checks if the characters in digits3 are only digits
        if (!Character.isDigit(digits3.charAt(i)))
        {
            System.out.println("non-numeric data");
            ret = false;
        }
    }
    // Tells the user if the characters they input are not over 3 digits
    for (int j = 3; j < digits3.length(); j++)
    {
        System.out.println("too many digits");
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: So, what question do you have?

Comment: I am trying to store the user input of String digits3 in an Array and then list how many times a number is used in said Array from 0-9.

Answer (score 1):

First the code. Then the explanations.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryAnalysis {

    public static boolean isNumeric(String digits3) {
        boolean ret = !digits3.equals("");
        for (int i = 2; i < digits3.length(); i++) {
            // Checks if the characters in digits3 are only digits
            if (!Character.isDigit(digits3.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.println("non-numeric data");
                ret = false;
            }
        }
        // Tells the user if the characters they input are not over 3 digits
        for (int j = 3; j < digits3.length(); j++) {
            System.out.println("too many digits");
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Lottery Analysis\n");

        // Create Scanner
        Scanner days = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask the user for how many days they will analyze
        System.out.print("How many days will you analyze? ");
        int analyze = days.nextInt();

        // Ask the user to enter 3 digits for each day
        System.out.println("\nEnter 3 digits for each day \n");
        Scanner scanDigits = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 1;

        // Store all digits used in digits3 in an array
        int[] frequencies = new int[10];

        // Make a loop that prints the number of days so the user can input the digits each time into that day
        String digits3;
        do {
            System.out.print("Day " + i + ": ");
            digits3 = scanDigits.nextLine();

            // Make sure the string used holds only 3 digits
            if (isNumeric(digits3)) {
                i++;
                char[] digits = digits3.toCharArray();
                for (char digit : digits) {
                    int index = digit - '0';
                    frequencies[index]++;
                }
            }
        }
        while (i <= analyze);

        // Print the Numbers and Frequencies from 0 to 9
        System.out.println("\nFrequencies\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < frequencies.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %d%n", j, frequencies[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I only changed code in method `main`.

1. The `frequencies` array needs to be declared before the `do-while` loop and not inside the loop. Note that Java initializes each element in the array to zero.
2. Inside the `do-while` loop you need to update the `frequencies` array.
3. You want to get the frequencies of all the digits but in your code you are only checking the first digit in each three-digit number that the user enters.
4. After the `do-while` loop terminates, you want to print all the elements in `frequencies`. In your code you are printing just the last, three-digit number that was entered by the user.
5. You only really need one `Scanner` (and not two) but if you use a single `Scanner`, then you need to add a call to method `nextLine` before you enter the `do-while` loop. Refer to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)
6. The code in your question does not compile because you reference [local] variable `val` outside of its scope. You declare it inside the following `if` statement (inside the `do-while` loop):

```java
if (isNumeric(digits3)) {
```

Hence its scope is the block associated with the `if` statement and you reference it after the `do-while` loop. The variable `val` only exists in the `if` statement block. In any case, the variable is not required and does not appear in my code, above.

Below is output from a sample run.

```
Lottery Analysis

How many days will you analyze? 5

Enter 3 digits for each day 

Day 1: 123
Day 2: 1234
too many digits
Day 2: abc
non-numeric data
Day 2: 456
Day 3: 789
Day 4: 012
Day 5: 345

Frequencies

0: 1
1: 2
2: 2
3: 2
4: 2
5: 2
6: 1
7: 1
8: 1
9: 1
```

### Edit

I didn't really look at the code of method `isNUmeric`, since it gave correct result for sample data in your question, but looking at it now, I see that it may give incorrect result, for example for the string `a12`, the method will return **true** and this is wrong. Here is my implementation:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String digits3) {
    boolean ret;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(digits3);
        ret = digits3.length() == 3;
        if (!ret) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a three digit number.");
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException x) {
        System.out.println("non-numeric data");
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```